# Do I need useCallback when running a function from a child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I understand that we should consider `useCallback` when we care about ensuring referential equality is considered during parent component renders. However, I am not clear if I need it in the following scenario where the parent is actually processing a ***child*** function.

```
import { ReactNode, useCallback, useState } from "react";

interface WrapperProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  onDoIt: () => Promise<void>;
}

type Status = "Do It" | "Doing It..." | "Did It";

export const Wrapper: React.FC<WrapperProps> = ({ children, onDoIt }) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<Status>("Do It");

  const handleDidIt = () => {
    setStatus("Did It");
  };

  const handleDoIt = async () => {
    setStatus("Doing It...");
    await onDoIt();
    handleDidIt();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleDoIt} disabled={status !== "Do It"}>
        {status}
      </button>
      <hr />
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState<string>("");

  const doIt = (): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        setResult("Done, thanks");
        return resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper onDoIt={doIt}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>{result}</p>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Should the hoc function `handleDoIt()` be wrapped in useCallback here?

```
  const handleDoItCallback = useCallback(async () => {
    setStatus("Doing It...");
    await onDoIt();
    handleDidIt();
  }, [onDoIt]);
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-tereshkova-5yi89e?file=/src/App.tsx:496-635)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it should be wrapped, as well as any other function it uses.

In this case:

```
const handleDidIt = useCallback(() => {
    setStatus("Did It");
}, []);
```

and then include in the deps array:

```
const handleDoIt = useCallback(async () => {
    setStatus("Doing It...");
    await onDoIt();
    handleDidIt();
  }, [onDoIt, handleDidIt]);
```

If you do not do this, then `handleDoIt` can fall out-of-date with the latest `handleDidIt`. In this case, it doesn't matter as it's just a constant state update, but it can with more complex logic.

Lastly, in the parent:

```
const doIt = useCallback((): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        setResult("Done, thanks");
        return resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
```

Notably, `setStatus` does not need to be included in either dependency array because it is always guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: I do not understand the -2 downvotes. This is how referential stability is supposed to be done.

Comment: First, since `onDoIt` is not wrapped in a `useCallback`, wrapping `handleDoIt` is useless, since it will get a new reference of `onDoIt` on every render. Then, [you should not wrap everything in `useCallback` without a good reason](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#should-you-add-usecallback-everywhere).

Comment: @Arkellys I didn't see that part of the code. `onDoIt` should _also_ be wrapped in a `useCallback`. Second, linked page: _"There is no significant harm to doing that either, so some teams choose to not think about individual cases, and memoize as much as possible."_. Regardless, OP wasn't about when to use useCallback, it was about how to use it properly.

Comment: OP asked if the function should be wrapped in `useCallback`, and I can quote the docs too: "There is no benefit to wrapping a function in `useCallback` in other cases."

Comment: The benefit is it makes usages lf useMemo and useEffect with dependencies easier later, because you do not need to go and wrap them reactively.

Comment: If function A calls function B, and function A is wrapped in a useCallback, function B should _also_ be wrapped in a useCallback. Should question A be wrapped? Irrelevant. Lets assume it is for purposes of answering the actual question.

Comment: It makes the code harder to read for something you might never need. OP will do as they want anyway.